# change tage page url to .html suffix magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to change this path :

```
/tag/product/list/tagId/4/
```

To something like this :

```
/tag/product/list/tagId/4.html
```

Magento supports .html too, I mean when u open this link : /tag/product/list/tagId/4.html it will work, but in product page and popular tag pages the url is /tag/product/list/tagId/4

I found the solution :

in this file :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Tag.php
```

change the return of the getTaggedProductsUrl() to

```
return Mage::getUrl('tag/product/list') .'tagId/' .$this->getTagId() .'.html';
```

Comment: why not using `.phtml`? I never used `html` though..

Comment: i created an extension, which uses .html in last place of url, and does something with is, in tag pages urls are like /tag/product/list/tagId/4/ so i cant use the extension, i need to change it to /tag/product/list/tagId/4.html so the extension will work, i just need to now how to change the url to this